# jQuery - onclick zoom function for multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask you about the way to reuse the code below for multiple images: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a8c9P/

How to avoid redundancy in the CSS code?

An updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/a8c9P/156

```
$("#imgSmall").click(function() {     
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", "http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/sports/music/pics/musical_notes.jpg");
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});

$("#imgBig").click(function(){
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", "");
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#overlayContent").hide();
});
```

Comment: Use classes instead of ids.

Comment: Are you trying to create some lightbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/a8c9P/157/

HTML

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="overlayContent">
    <img id="imgBig" src="" alt="" width="400" />
</div>

<img class="imgSmall" width="200" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/space/earth/pics/a17_h_148_22718.gif" alt="" />


<img class="imgSmall" width="200" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/space/earth/pics/a17_h_148_22718.gif" alt="" />

<img class="imgSmall" width="200" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/space/earth/pics/a17_h_148_22718.gif" alt="" />
```

JS

```
$(".imgSmall").click(function(){
    $("#imgBig").attr("src",$(this).attr('src'));
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});

$("#imgBig").click(function(){
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", "");
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#overlayContent").hide();
});
```

CSS

```
#overlay{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: #000; 
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70) !important;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;

}

#overlayContent{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}

#contentGallery{
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#imgBig, .imgSmall{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First - if you are going to use an id it should always be unique. That in mind, any time you want particular behavior that you want to apply to many elements in a "jQuery" manner - this is a perfect case to use a class instead of an id. An example of this:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
    $("#imgBig").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#overlayContent").show();
});
```

You'll note that I use `this` which is a reference to the exact item that was clicked! Now you don't have to worry about having many elements of the same type!

[**SEE THE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8c9P/158/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is multiple IDs and an HTML Class to handle the CSS.  Each element can only have one ID, but it can inherit multiple classes.  Define .imgSmall and .imgBig classes, use those to handle your CSS, and then use whatever ID scheme suits you for the click detection.

I would recommend something like img1, img1, img2 and bigimg1, bigimg2, bigimg3, because that would let you generate all of your html in a loop.